# Apache2 not able to use fopen php function

Tags: php, html, apache, raspberry-pi

The following code is running on an apache2 webserver running on a raspberry pi 4 but the the fopen function is not currently working, I think it is something to do with the permissions but am unsure how to fix them

```
<?php

                $listFile = fopen("todolist.html", "w") or die("Unable to open file");

                $startString = "
                <!DOCTYPE html>
                <html>
                  <head>
                    <meta name='viewport' content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1' />
                    <title>ToDo List</title>
                    <link rel='stylesheet' href='../loginPage/style.css' />
                    <link rel='icon' href='../loginPage/images/websiteIcon.ico' />
                  </head>
                
                  <body>
                    <div class='container' style='width: 80%'>
                      <h1>ToDo List</h1>
                      <table>
                ";
                fwrite($listFile, $startString . "\n");
```

I have tried chmod 644 todolist.html but did not change the outcome

Comment: What are the directory permissions of your app? Who is the owner of the todolist.html, is it `www-data`? Also `chmod 644` is setting only read permission for groups and others,  are you looking for `chmod 664`?

Comment: Can I suggest you enable error reporting and/or logging so you can see the actual error message? Apache does not really execute PHP functions, it just invokes the PHP interpreter.